# Primitive roots in integer rings of number fields with class number 1

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, unique-factorization-domains, primitive-roots

In number fields that are PIDs, i.e., with class number 1, we have unique factorization of integral elements into primes, much like we do in $\Bbb Z$. Suppose $\pi$ is such a prime element in $R$, the integer ring of our number field. What can we say about the structure of $R/\pi R$?

In the case $R=\Bbb Z$, the quotient has a cyclic multiplicative group, i.e., primitive roots exist for rational primes. Is that also true in other uniquely factoring integer rings?

I know that rational primes are not necessarily prime in such rings; I’m asking about elements that are prime. Can we state necessary and sufficient conditions on an integral ring for the primitive root theorem to hold?

I have searched for an answer on MSE and Google to no avail. I have also looked at the proof that rational primes have primitive roots, but it is not clear to me whether this generalizes to integer rings in other number fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $R$ is the ring of integers of a number field and $\mathfrak{p}$ is a non-zero prime ideal of $R$, then $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is a finite field, and so its multiplicative group is cyclic. In particular, this holds when $R$ is a PID and $\mathfrak{p}=(\pi)$, though these additional assumptions are not necessary.

Comment: Thank you. The piece I was missing is that the multiplicative group of a finite field must be cyclic. I have now located and understood a proof of that fact. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be the ring of integers of a number field.

When $\pi$ is a prime element, that is 
$\pi$ generates a prime ideal, then $R/\pi R$ is a finite field.
The multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic; it always has
a "primitive root".

Comment: See my comment on Carmichael’s answer. Thanks very much :)  Now I just have to decide which one to accept, lol.

Comment: These answers are both great; I literally flipped a coin to decide which one to accept. Thank you, again. :)